# TypeORM: How to create a bidirectional one-to-many relation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I have read all the documentation for [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm), but it doesn't say how to create a bidirectional one-to-many relation.

It says:

> In many-to-one / one-to-many relation, the owner side is always many-to-one. **It means that the class that uses @ManyToOne will store the id of the related object.**

But I do not want that, I want the relation ID in both sides of the relation, like so:

- Album: id, name, photoId.
- Photo: id, albumsId

I am not even sure if this possible, as it doesn't seem to be present in the docs.

Comment: Did you try with a @JoinTable()?

Comment: @Jérémy isn't it used only for many-to-many relations?